# How would I filter posts by department using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to be able to filter a list of posts by department and tag and content using angularjs ng-options. I've tried the following but its not working.

The Code - Not sure why the ng-repeat is not working on here. But its working fine on my editor.

Basically, I need to be able to filter based on tags as well and avoid repeated tags or departments.

Thanks

```js
angular.module('selectFilter', [])
  .controller('NewsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.articles = [{
        "url": "porta-volutpat-erat",
        "title": "porta volutpat erat",
        "summary": "Nam congue, risus semper porta volutpat, quam pede lobortis ligula, sit amet eleifend pede libero quis orci. Nullam molestie nibh in lectus. Pellentesque at nulla.",
        "content": "Sed sagittis. Nam congue, risus semper porta volutpat, quam pede lobortis ligula, sit amet eleifend pede libero quis orci. Nullam molestie nibh in lectus.\n\nPellentesque at nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Cras in purus eu magna vulputate luctus.\n\nCum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus vestibulum sagittis sapien. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.\n\nEtiam vel augue. Vestibulum rutrum rutrum neque. Aenean auctor gravida sem.",
        "thumbnailImage": "http://dummyimage.com/215x173.png/ff4444/ffffff",
        "departments": ["One", "Four"],
        "tags": [
          "Study",
          "Business",
          "Science",
          "Law"
        ],
        "isFeatured": true,
        "publishedDate": "9/12/2017",
        "type": "Content"
      },
      {
        "url": "nibh-in-quis",
        "title": "nibh in quis",
        "summary": "Nulla neque libero, convallis eget, eleifend luctus, ultricies eu, nibh. Quisque id justo sit amet sapien dignissim vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla dapibus dolor vel est.",
        "content": "Integer tincidunt ante vel ipsum. Praesent blandit lacinia erat. Vestibulum sed magna at nunc commodo placerat.\n\nPraesent blandit. Nam nulla. Integer pede justo, lacinia eget, tincidunt eget, tempus vel, pede.\n\nMorbi porttitor lorem id ligula. Suspendisse ornare consequat lectus. In est risus, auctor sed, tristique in, tempus sit amet, sem.\n\nFusce consequat. Nulla nisl. Nunc nisl.\n\nDuis bibendum, felis sed interdum venenatis, turpis enim blandit mi, in porttitor pede justo eu massa. Donec dapibus. Duis at velit eu est congue elementum.",
        "thumbnailImage": "http://dummyimage.com/135x135.png/dddddd/000000",
        "departments": ["One", "Four", "five"],
        "tags": [
          "Research",
          "Life",
          "Business",
          "Social"
        ],
        "isFeatured": true,
        "publishedDate": "3/16/2018",
        "type": "Content"
      }
    ];

  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="NewsController">
  <select ng-model="selectedDept" ng-options="d as departments for d in articles">
    <option value="">Select Department</option>
  </select>


  <article ng-repeat="article in articles">
    <h1><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h1>
    <p>{{ article.summary }}</p>
    <a href="{{ article.url }}">Read more &rarr;</a>
    <span class="badge" ng-repeat="departments in article.departments">{{ departments }}</span>
  </article>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you could prepare the actual departments array like shown below and add the filtering like below.

```
<article ng-repeat="article in articles | filter: { departments: selectedDept}">
```

Below is an example for reference!

```js
angular.module('selectFilter', [])
  .controller('NewsController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.articles = [{
        "url": "porta-volutpat-erat",
        "title": "porta volutpat erat",
        "summary": "Nam congue, risus semper porta volutpat, quam pede lobortis ligula, sit amet eleifend pede libero quis orci. Nullam molestie nibh in lectus. Pellentesque at nulla.",
        "content": "Sed sagittis. Nam congue, risus semper porta volutpat, quam pede lobortis ligula, sit amet eleifend pede libero quis orci. Nullam molestie nibh in lectus.\n\nPellentesque at nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Cras in purus eu magna vulputate luctus.\n\nCum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Vivamus vestibulum sagittis sapien. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.\n\nEtiam vel augue. Vestibulum rutrum rutrum neque. Aenean auctor gravida sem.",
        "thumbnailImage": "http://dummyimage.com/215x173.png/ff4444/ffffff",
        "departments": ["One", "Four"],
        "tags": [
          "Study",
          "Business",
          "Science",
          "Law"
        ],
        "isFeatured": true,
        "publishedDate": "9/12/2017",
        "type": "Content"
      },
      {
        "url": "nibh-in-quis",
        "title": "nibh in quis",
        "summary": "Nulla neque libero, convallis eget, eleifend luctus, ultricies eu, nibh. Quisque id justo sit amet sapien dignissim vestibulum. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nulla dapibus dolor vel est.",
        "content": "Integer tincidunt ante vel ipsum. Praesent blandit lacinia erat. Vestibulum sed magna at nunc commodo placerat.\n\nPraesent blandit. Nam nulla. Integer pede justo, lacinia eget, tincidunt eget, tempus vel, pede.\n\nMorbi porttitor lorem id ligula. Suspendisse ornare consequat lectus. In est risus, auctor sed, tristique in, tempus sit amet, sem.\n\nFusce consequat. Nulla nisl. Nunc nisl.\n\nDuis bibendum, felis sed interdum venenatis, turpis enim blandit mi, in porttitor pede justo eu massa. Donec dapibus. Duis at velit eu est congue elementum.",
        "thumbnailImage": "http://dummyimage.com/135x135.png/dddddd/000000",
        "departments": ["One", "Four", "five"],
        "tags": [
          "Research",
          "Life",
          "Business",
          "Social"
        ],
        "isFeatured": true,
        "publishedDate": "3/16/2018",
        "type": "Content"
      }
    ];
    $scope.departments = [];
    for(var item of $scope.articles){
      for(var a of item['departments']){
        if($scope.departments.indexOf(a) === -1){
          $scope.departments.push(a);
        }
      }
    }
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="NewsController" ng-app="selectFilter">
  <select ng-model="selectedDept" ng-options="d for d in departments">
    <option value="">Select Department</option>
  </select>


  <article ng-repeat="article in articles | filter: { departments: selectedDept}">
    <h1><a href="{{ article.url }}">{{ article.title }}</a></h1>
    <p>{{ article.summary }}</p>
    <a href="{{ article.url }}">Read more &rarr;</a>
    <span class="badge" ng-repeat="departments in article.departments">{{ departments }}</span>
  </article>

</div>
```

Comment: How would I add additional filters since I also would like to have a separate dropdown for Tags and Content. Thanks

Comment: @Said Prepare each list of options for the ng-options like shown in my example, then you can add more filters like `<article ng-repeat="article in articles | filter: { departments: selectedDept, tags: selectedTags}">`

Answer (score 0):

**Two ways**:

one is to create a custom filter:

```
myApp.filter('customFilter', [ function() {
    return function (object) {
        var array = [];
        angular.forEach(object, function (post) {
            if (post.Field == 'Department' || post.Field == 'Tags' || post.Field == 'Content')
                array.push(post);
        });
        return array;
    };
}]);
```

Then use it:

```
 <select ng-model="selectedDept" ng-options="d.departments for d in articles | customFilter">
    <option value="">Select Department</option>
  </select>
```

or use the filter pipe:

```
 ng-options="d.departments for d in articles | filter:{field:'Department'}">
```